# ActiveRecord establish_connection using Heroku config vars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I am trying to use `establish_connection` in `ActiveRecord` to connect to an external database in my Rails 4 app. I want to use the Heroku config vars to do this so that I do not have to enter my `database.yml` into source control.

My model is set up like this:

```
class Pgconn < ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    #heroku config vars
    :adapter => ENV['PG_ADAPTER'],
    :database => ENV['PG_DB'],
    :username => ENV['PG_USER'],
    :password => ENV['PG_PW'],
    :host => ENV['PG_HOST']
  )
end

class Pgdb < Pgconn

  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = 'test'

  def self.getInfo(name)
    get = connection.query("SELECT * FROM test)
    get
  end
end
```

This gives the following error in `heroku logs`:
`syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

When I add `{}` around my config vars I get an error:
`superclass must be a Class (ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool given) (TypeError)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define the class `Pgconn` extending the result of an `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`. That is not valid Ruby.

It's like doing something like the following

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
  end
end

class Something < Foo.bar(
    # ...
  )
end
```

This is incorrect. I have no idea what you are trying to do, but that's definitely not correct.

Comment: I am trying to establish_connection to a database using heroku config vars. any idea how I can modify/combine the above classes to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are using Rails follow the Heroku instructions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4 there is no need to trigger the connection manually

Comment: The question that you tagged as a duplicate does not have an answer. This is for a second database not the app database.